# Separate Hibernate instances by two different JVM processes anomaly

Tags: java, linux, hibernate

I'm getting a weird scenario - I have two hibernate instances(say, A and B) being run by two separate JVM processes - Please don't ask why, but I have to. When A commits(trans.commit()) and writes to a table T in MySql then when B reads the same record from T, it gets stale data.

A and B each has a single session object say - sessionA and sessionB. So, no new openSession() is being invoked.

Can anyone please provide me a clue as of why this is happening?

Comment: has the transaction on A been committed before B's transaction was started? do you have 2nd level cache enabled?

Comment: Yes, A does a trancation.commit() and then B reads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding other alternatives: If you are using Hibernate as your ORM(Object Relational Mapping) Tool , Then you can check **LockOptions** in hibernate documentations.
You can use **LockMode.Upgrade** on the entity which is inserted and then retrieved from Database.

Summary : Check out **LockOptions** in hibernate and apply **LockMode**  **Upgrade** in such conditions.

If still you face any issues then post that.
Hope it would provide you resolution to your issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely need more information on your transaction boundaries and cache settings. To determine if it is a caching problem, run the following code just before instance B reads the data instance A writes:

```
    session.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictCollectionRegions();
    session.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictDefaultQueryRegion();
    session.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictEntityRegions();
    session.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictQueryRegions();
```

This evicts all configured caches. If the read on B works afterwards then you have a caching issue between the instances(likely). If it the read on B still does not work, I would check the DB via terminal to ensure A's data was committed.

Comment: It does a trancation.commit() and then B reads, is there a question of cache settings?

Answer (score 2):

Which Database engine you are using to create your database in MySQL.
if you are using **InnoDB** as the database engine change it to **MyISAM**.
This is one of the most common issues when you create multiple instances of hibernate SessionFactory.
One would think that this could be an issue with Second Level Caching if you are using it but its is not that.
So changing database engine will for sure help you resolve your issues.

Tell me if it worked for you or not.
I will provide other solutions if this does not work.

Comment: Hi, I'm not allowed to change to MyISAM. Any other alternatives?

Comment: Then you will have to create and destroy SessionFactory each time. I feel sorry for this behavior of Hibernate as well as of MySQL InnoDB engine.

Comment: No problem with that. Thanks for you help! :)